# Optional fields from JSON datasource JasperReports

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I'm using JSON data source for creating report in JasperReport. Inside iReport field is declared as Integer. This field is used in row among other fields.

Input JSON example:

```
[{
    "dateFrom": "01.12.2016",
    "dateTo": "01.12.2016",
    "someOptionalNumber": 12
},
{
    "dateFrom": "01.12.2016",
    "dateTo": "01.12.2016"
}, {
    "dateFrom": "01.12.2016",
    "dateTo": "01.12.2016",
    "someOptionalNumber": 11
}]
```

Field declaration:

```
<field name="someOptionalNumber" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

Problem is that in input JSON someOptionalNumber is optional and as such doesn't exists in every row. Can field be optional ?

When I run such JSON i get this error:

**Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unable to get value for field 'someOptionalNumber' of class 'java.lang.Integer'**

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[JRException: Unable to get value for field 'someOptionalNumber' of class 'java.lang.Integer']]
...
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unable to get value for field 'someOptionalNumber' of class 'java.lang.Integer'
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource.getFieldValue(JsonDataSource.java:241)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1358)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1259)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1235)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1588)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:149)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:939)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:871)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:114)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
    at reporting.engine.ReportEngine$.reporting$engine$ReportEngine$$createPDF(ReportEngine.scala:64)
...
Caused by: org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: Unparseable number: ""
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale.BaseLocaleConverter.convert(BaseLocaleConverter.java:241)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale.LocaleConvertUtilsBean.convert(LocaleConvertUtilsBean.java:285)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractTextDataSource.convertStringValue(JRAbstractTextDataSource.java:70)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource.getFieldValue(JsonDataSource.java:231)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: ""
    at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:385)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale.converters.DecimalLocaleConverter.parse(DecimalLocaleConverter.java:253)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale.converters.IntegerLocaleConverter.parse(IntegerLocaleConverter.java:218)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale.BaseLocaleConverter.convert(BaseLocaleConverter.java:232)
```

Comment: In jasper reports, there cannot be an optional field. Either the field can have null values. But optional is not supportable.

Comment: You should be seeing `null` values wherever the JSON property is missing. 
The error says that the engine has encountered an empty string when a number was expected. This means that your JSON may not be consistent for that property. You may have to fix the JSON data for this to properly work.

Comment: What JasperReports version are you using?  The problem might have been fixed by http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreportsr-library/issues/3742, that is in JasperReports 6.0 or newer.

Comment: I'm using 5.5.1 version

Comment: Yes, new version solved problem ! You can write answer dada67, and I can endorse you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using 5.5.1 version of JasperReports, upgrade to latest version (6.3.1) solved issue as [dada67](https://stackoverflow.com/users/983559/dada67) sugested